# Prevent widget tree from gaining focus

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to prevent a widget tree gaining focus ?

I want to prevent *Child column* or any nested children (Field 1, Field 2) from gaining focus without disabling the fields, *Field 3* should still be focusable. how to achieve it ?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Example'),
    ),
    body: Column(
      key: Key("Parent column"),
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          key: Key("Child column"),
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              key: Key("Field 1"),
            ),
            TextField(
              key: Key("Field 2"),
            )
          ],
        ),
        TextField(
          key: Key("Field 3"),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: tried `IgnorePointer` / `AbsorbPointer`?

Answer (score 8):

Use `ExcludeFocus` widget as this will also prevent getting the focus by traversal (tab key). You may also want to wrap the widget with `IgnorePointer` to prevent clicks to the subtree.

See also [Preventing some controls in an application from being focusable](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/focus#controlling-what-gets-focus)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @pskink suggestion.

This is actually very easy implement: Just wrap the widget tree inside the `IgnorePointer`. `shouldIgnore` is the variable controlling if *Child column* and it's children should get any touch events.

```
bool shouldIgnore = true;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Example'),
    ),
     body: Column(
      key: Key("Parent column"),
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        IgnorePointer(
          ignoring: shouldIgnore,
          child: Column(
            key: Key("Child column"),
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                key: Key("Field 1"),
              ),
              TextField(
                key: Key("Field 2"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          key: Key("Field 3"),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```